# Approximate function only with previous points

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, forecasting

I would like to approximate a polynomial function (degree 3 for now), with an input of 10 steps to forecast the 20 next points. To do this, I use a simple dense model with one neuron, but I'm not having good results and don't know how to optimize the problem.

What I want to approximate:
[image]

The results I obtained:
[image]

My code is simple as that:

```
class Modeles:
    def __init__(self, TO_FORECAST): 
        self.Model= None
        self.TO_FORECAST = TO_FORECAST

    def model(self):
        self.Model = Sequential([
                                    Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1:, :]),
                                    Dense(1, activation='relu'),
                                    Dense(self.TO_FORECAST, activation='linear', kernel_initializer=initializers.zeros()),
                                    Reshape([self.TO_FORECAST, 1])
                                    ])

class CompilationFitting:
    def __init__(self, model, Data):
        self.model = model
        self.Data = Data
        self.History = None
        self.Prediction = None
    
    def compile(self):
        self.model.compile(loss=losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
                    metrics=[metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

    def fit(self):
        MAX_EPOCHS = 100
        self.History = self.model.fit(self.Data.X, self.Data.y, batch_size=16, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                                validation_data=(self.Data.X, self.Data.y))

    def predict(self):
        self.Prediction = self.model.predict(self.Data.X)
```

Comment: One neuron is too simple. Add more couple of layers.

Comment: ok i'll try it.